# Why do I get 'google.cloud.aiplatform.constants' has no attribute 'SUPPORTED_REGIONS error for Vertex AI init?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to set up mlops for Vertex AI, following [this notebook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/mlops-with-vertex-ai/blob/main/01-dataset-management.ipynb). It works until, near the end, I try:

```
vertex_ai.init(
project=PROJECT,
    location=REGION)
```

which gives:

```
 module 'google.cloud.aiplatform.constants' has no attribute 'SUPPORTED_REGIONS
```

I am using `us-central1` which is supported. I wondered if maybe `from google.cloud import aiplatform as vertex_ai` has been changed but don't know how to find out. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I just recreated a User-Managed Notebook following the same notebook as you, and I didn’t have any problem. I think that you are using an [older version of python-aiplatform](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/releases) Or my other guess is that the region is incorrect because my default region when I was creating the notebook was `us-west1`. The command to upgrade the library is the following: `pip3 install google-cloud-aiplatform --upgrade`.

Comment: Thank you, the upgrade fixed it. If you want to add an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the same Notebook as you, even though I didn't have any issue. What could be happening to you is that you are using an [older version of the library](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/releases).

You can use the command to upgrade the library that is the following one: `pip3 install google-cloud-aiplatform --upgrade`.

Sometimes this happens with the basic installation of the library; the problems could be in the [dependencies, versions and indirectly permissions](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform#installation).